# How to enable TLS on OpenLDAP

Tags: ssl, ldap, openldap, tls

I am using CentOS 5.I have a problem enabling TLS (or ssl) on OpenLDAP server. I followed this [tutorial](http://www.openldap.org/faq/data/cache/185.html).
I generated the certificates and I configured the path in `slapd.conf` as following

```
TLSCertificateFile      /path/to/server-certificate.pem
TLSCertificateKeyFile   /path/to/private-key.pem
TLSCACertificateFile    /path/to/CA-certificates
```

I used the command

```
slapd -h "ldap:/// ldaps:///"
```

to enable listener on port 636.

I can't create a connection to `ldaps://myhost:636` (I tried to create a connection with a client and liferay ldap)

I haven't problems if I not use TLS.

Did I miss some steps in configuration here?

***Edit***

using the command:

```
openssl s_client -connect host:port
```

I obtain

[image]

Comment: Use the `openssl` command to see what exactly goes wrong. Like so: `openssl s_client -connect host:port`.

Comment: Also check using `netstat` or `lsof` if your slapd is really listening on 636.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you have problem with your CA certificate. You can check TLS connection from the serer using:

```
$ ldapwhoami -H ldap:// -x -ZZ
anonymous
```

Check your `/etc/ldap/ldap.conf` for this line:

```
TLS_CACERT /etc/ssl/certs/ca_server.pem
```

Best way how to modify LDAP configuration is creating `addcerts.ldif` with following content:

```
dn: cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcTLSCACertificateFile
olcTLSCACertificateFile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca_server.pem
-
add: olcTLSCertificateFile
olcTLSCertificateFile: /etc/ssl/certs/ldap_server.pem
-
add: olcTLSCertificateKeyFile
olcTLSCertificateKeyFile: /etc/ssl/private/ldap_server.key
```

and apply change:

```
ldapmodify -H ldapi:// -Y EXTERNAL -f addcerts.ldif
```

Lastly check `/etc/default/slapd` and make sure services contains `ldaps:///`:

```
SLAPD_SERVICES="ldap:/// ldapi:/// ldaps:///"
```

Afterwards just reload `slapd` service and check connection to LDAP using the first command.

Comment: I spent some time on this today because I was trying to revise the list of TLS protocols available (specifically, disable everything except for TLSv1.2). I needed to add another attribute with name 'olcTLSCipherSuites' and (because by OpenLDAP server was built against GnuTLS), I used the attribute value `SECURE256:SECURE:-VERS-TLS1.1:-VERS-TLS1.0:-VERS-SSL3.0:-MD5:-SHA1:-ARCFOUR-128`.

Comment: Looks like the `ldaps:///` is not in fact required, as per https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/openldap-server.html, at the end of the TLS section: "Contratry to popular belief, you do not need ldaps:// in /etc/default/slapd in order to use encryption."

Comment: `ldaps:///` is required if you want your OpenLDAP server to listen on port 636 (`ldaps`). Without this setting in `SLAPD_SERVICES`, `slapd` will only listen on port 389 (`ldap`). The latter supports StartTLS, i.e. upgrading a connection from unencrypted LDAP to TLS-encrypted LDAP, whereas 636/ldaps will _always_ enforce encrypted connections.

Comment: Quite old entry, I know. Anyways: Trying to feed this to my Directory (openLDAP 2.4.57) results in `ldap_modify: Other (e.g., implementation specific) error (80)`.